# How do I start a Scala project in Intellij? I can't find the scala SDK

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am new to Scala. I installed Scala plugin in IntellJ.

When I say New project, I don't know where the Scala SDK is . 
Can someone help please?

Comment: Wherever you installed your Scala SDK. And I do not think it asks for Scala SDK, it asks only for Java SDK.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html

Comment: We can't tell you where you installed Scala. Only you know that.

Answer (score 0):

After you installed the scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (don't forget to restart your IDEA) you should be able to create scala project.
[image]

Moreover, I highly recommend using Lightbend Activator for scala projects (https://www.lightbend.com/activator/download) because the templates already bring the package structure and the appropriate libraries for mostly all basic use cases.

Comment: It asks for Scala SDK.  THEY didnt let me post my screen shot

Comment: Scala sdk is basically the scala compiler. The latest stable version is 2.11.8 (http://www.scala-lang.org/). You can download it there, and then point Intellij to it.